# Python text file Excel, inserting number into excell not in correct format

Tags: python, excel, file, text

> > Hi I have a written a code in python that reads the number from text file, put them in an array.An the corresponding array are inserted into corresponding excel cell. But my number are being store as a text(String) in a cell, so my formula's in excel cannot process them.I have to convert them to number manually.

Is there a way to save this as number when inserting into excel.
I am new at python.below is my code:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) 
 with open("C:/Users/................../Python36-32/data.txt","r") as data:
    temp=data.readline()
    temp1=data.readline()
    temp2=data.readline()
    temp3=data.readline()
    temp4=data.readline()

>>> m5F=temp.split(",")
>>> m5G=temp1.split(",")
>>> m5I=temp2.split(",")
>>> m5J=temp3.split(",")
>>> m5K=temp4.split(",")
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb=load_workbook(filename='template.xlsx')
>>> ws=wb.active
>>> ws['F22']=m5F[0]
>>> ws['F23']=m5F[1]
>>> ws['F28']=m5F[2]
>>> ws['F29']=m5F[3]
>>> ws['F34']=m5F[4]
>>> ws['F35']=m5F[5]
>>> ws['F40']=m5F[6]
>>> ws['F41']=m5F[7]
>>> ws['G22']=m5G[0]
>>> ws['G23']=m5G[1]
>>> ws['G28']=m5G[2]
>>> ws['G29']=m5G[3]
>>> ws['G34']=m5G[4]
>>> ws['G35']=m5G[5]
>>> ws['G40']=m5G[6]
>>> ws['G41']=m5G[7]
>>> ws['I54']=m5I[0]
>>> ws['I55']=m5I[1]
>>> ws['I64']=m5I[2]
>>> ws['J54']=m5J[0]
>>> ws['J55']=m5J[1]
>>> ws['J64']=m5J[2]
>>> ws['K54']=m5K[0]
>>> ws['J55']=m5J[1]
>>> ws['J64']=m5J[2]
>>> wb.save('New.xlsx')
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)** method to convert the string number to an integer before saving the xlsx file.

**Ex:**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb=load_workbook('template.xlsx')
ws=wb.active

ws['A11']=int("1")            #ws['F22']=int(m5F[0])

wb.save('template.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please accept ans(tick symbol) if it solved your problem.